# Clearcase: Files not visible to view

Tags: clearcase, configuration-management

I just saw a very odd thing, I have a co-worker who has their configspec setup to look at the main branch, and earlier this morning he could see files in a certain folder, he hasn't changed that view and all of a sudden they were gone.

I took a look at the folder's node, and when I compare it with the previous version, it shows that there were like 4 files removed in the latest version of main (that was checked in probably a month ago, so long before the problem began).

So my question is why can I see them when I compare nodes, but not in the folder?

I compared the node I was looking at to previous, so it wasn't like I picked another node I wasn't looking at.

This is so confusing.

EDIT: This only happens with this one folder, the other like 10 folders in the view are all accessible and have the files visible too (and they're all branched the same).

EDIT#2: So they were able to see the files again, (And now I hear it's happened to a second person) by copying out the configspec, stopping the view, starting the view, and copying the configspec back in. Viola the files are back, but that still really doesn't explain what could cause that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual explanation is when you have the directory checked-out (unreserved) in your view:
Any change made by others (like `rmname` 4 files) won't be visible until you undo-checkout said directory.

The "all of a sudden" part means he was probably in a *dynamic* view, in which case you also have the possibility of an "eclipsed" element (a directory in this case): once the private directory (with the same name than the versionned directory, which is the definition of an eclipsed element in a dynamic view) is moved/removed, then the versionned directory takes its place (with the right content, i.e. minus 4 files).

Comment: The folder isn't checked out, and the files were visible this morning earlier, with no (from what I'm told) change.
EDIT: Meaning, the changes that we should be seeing have been checked in for the last month, and should still be visible as they were this morning.

Comment: The folder has been checked in for quite some time, and wasn't a private view, he was seeing it in a checked in view and yes it was a dynamic view, he was able to see a configured folders configured contents and "all of a sudden" he wasn't able to find it.
Edit: I.E. it wasn't an eclipsed situation, I have verified this as of now.

Comment: @onaclov2000: did he try to recreate another dynamic view with the same config spec and see if this issue is seen again in said new view?

Comment: I'm not sure if he tried that himself, but I can see the files from another view myself, I'll check.

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same issue.  Turns out the horizontal bar dividing the file view and the "helpful text" was all the way to the top and thus hid the files.  No easy indication that it's hidden.  Had to look at co-worker's working view to realize that there's a horizontal bar to move.
[image: Image showing CC Explorer with files hidden]

Comment: That is a weird "functionality" of clearcase, however in the above case it's not the same issue, but hopefully this will help others who run across your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds stupid, but what is the protection of this folder? Does he has "read" access to it?

Comment: I checked that he has owner read/write/execute, group read/write/execute, and the last one "other" he has read/execute.